# In Azure App Service, error when configuring wildcard Custom Domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, wildcard-subdomain, custom-domain, azure-custom-domain

When configuring my wildcard custom domain in an app service, I have en error message saying plainly:

"Attribuer un domaine personnalisé

Impossible d’attribuer le domaine personnalisé *.mydomain.com"

Or in English:

"Configure a Custom Domain

Unable to configure the Custom domain *.mydomain.com"

MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) says that is is possible to set a wildcard domain, gives step to achieve it, but in my case it doesn't work. My domain is managed by Azure Domaine App Service.
I set the CNAME record and the TXT record correctly, I'm able to configure a custom subdomain such as test.mydomain.com, but when I try *.mydomain.com, I still have this error.

Did someone already manage to do this?

Comment: Please describe the error message part in English so that you can get help from other users.

Comment: Edited. The message doesn't give a lot of detail, so I'm not sure this is gonna be of any help...